# Excel Power Query, VBA and recalculation: It's complicated

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I recently got started with Excel Power Query, retrieving data from SharePoint. Things worked nicely until I noticed that some cells in a worksheet doing lookups on the query result (both in the same workbook) did not get calculated. The value just showed 0. When I selected the cell and hit enter, recalculation for the cell happened and the correct value was shown. Calculation method is "Automatic except data tables" (I hope I translated this correctly).

I traced the issue to a specific UDF I use within many of my UDFs, a function checking whether a range (or more precise a parameter) has been recalculated and if not, the outer UDF is exited immediately. This is a common recommendation found on many sites to improve performance and I never had any issues with it - until the arrival of power query, that is.

There seem to be a few possible solutions which one could pursue:

- Somehow trigger a full recalculation&rebuild after a query is executed. Would require some kind of trigger or event (which I currently don't know).
- Make the UDF which checks if the argument is dirty more intelligent. By the observed behavior, my takeaway is, that the table containing the query result always counts as dirty(?). If so, teaching the UDF about this, would help.
- Make sure that the query results always count as clean in excel.

I would rather avoid the first solution.
The third solution sound as if it may have unwanted side effects, so my preference would be to the second venue: Improve the UDF checking if an argument is dirty.

Here it is in its current state (leading to the above described behavior):

```
Public Function chkRngCalculated(theParameter As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim vHasFormula     As Variant
    chkRngCalculated = True
    On Error GoTo Fail
    If TypeOf theParameter Is Excel.Range Then
        vHasFormula = theParameter.HasFormula
        ' HasFormula can be True, False or Null:
        ' Null if the range contains a mix of Formulas and data
        If IsNull(vHasFormula) Then vHasFormula = True
        If vHasFormula Then
            ' CountA returns 0 if any of the cells are not yet calculated
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(theParameter) = 0 Then chkRngCalculated = False
        End If
    ' a calculated parameter is Empty if it references uncalculated cells
    ElseIf VarType(theParameter) = vbEmpty Then
        chkRngCalculated = False
    End If
    Exit Function
Fail:
    chkRngCalculated = False
End Function
```

It is usually called in one of the first lines of a UDF, never from Excel cells directly obviously. The following shows how it is called from my lookup function:

```
Public Function searchKeyed(target As Range, rowKey As Variant, columnKey As Variant) As Variant
    If Not chkRngCalculated(target) Then Exit Function
...
```

I verified that, if I comment out the if statement, the values do get updated correctly upon query update.

Background updating of the queries has been turned off. Switching to 'Automatic' recalculation from 'Automatic except data tables' does not change the described behavior.

Has someone had a similar experience and found a solution?

Comment: What if you make the UDF volatile?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile

Comment: Well, that kinda works. However, on hitting F9, not all cells were recalculated, only some, on repitition eventually all cells are calculated. However, turning a lookup function into a volatile function is just wrong. It will drag down performance massively. Also, it is such a servere side effect. It means I would have to apply this 'fix' to all UDFs and I'm maintaining quite a library. So this can not be the final solution.